# Unable to Parse XMl after unwrapping soap body

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have been trying hard to parse an xml string, but all to no avail

```
<EnquirySingleItemResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">                  <EnquirySingleItemResult>
    <Response>
      <MSG>SUCCESS</MSG>
      <INFO>TESTING</INFO>
    </Response>   </EnquirySingleItemResult> </EnquirySingleItemResponse>
```

My Code returns null or the texts in the xml tags no matter how i parse it. I have checked some post, but they seem not to be working.
See my code snipped below

```
 XElement anotherUnwrappedResponse = ( from _xml in axdoc.Descendants(tempuri + "EnquirySingleItemResponse")
                                       select _xml).FirstOrDefault();

        string response = anotherUnwrappedResponse.Value;
```

axdoc.Descendants is used because i unwrapped the soap body, to have the xml above

Comment: Please provide minimal *but complete* codes demonstrating the problem. Currently, your codes is incomplete. Some variables are not defined and not assigned any value. If we define and populate the variables properly on our own, then it will print `SUCCESSTESTING` without any problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
            "<EnquirySingleItemResponse xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">" +
                "<EnquirySingleItemResult>" +
                "<Response>" +
                  "<MSG>SUCCESS</MSG>" +
                  "<INFO>TESTING</INFO>" +
                "</Response>   </EnquirySingleItemResult> </EnquirySingleItemResponse>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);
            string msg = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "MSG").FirstOrDefault().Value;
            string info = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "INFO").FirstOrDefault().Value;
        }
    }
}
​
```